# Using Facebook C# SDK in .Net 2.0 framework

Tags: facebook, dll, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-login

I want to use Facebook C# SDK in my website to allow users to login using their facebook account. My website is built in .Net Framwork 2.0 . I have .Net Framework 3.5 and Visual Studio 2008 installed on my box.  As per the documentation I saw online, I tried to download the Nuget command line tool and got the error saying that I need to have .Net Framework v4.0.30319.

I also tried to reference Facebook.dll (which I got using Nuget on a machine with .Net 4.0) in my website. But that gave errors saying that the assembly was built in a newer runtime.

How can I get Facebook.dll that works with .Net 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the latest version by opening the following url in a browser.

http://nuget.org/api/v2/package/Facebook

To download a specific version use the following url instead

http://nuget.org/api/v2/package/Facebook/6.0.20

Then extract it using your favorite zip program.

We don't support .net 2.0. You at least need to be on .net 3.5 SP1.

And make sure you are referencing the right Facebook.dll under net35-client folder.

Comment: Thanks. But I cannot upgrade to .Net 3.5. I need to get the Facebook.dll that works with .Net 2.0. I read that Facebook Developer Toolkit works with .Net 2.0. I downloaded Facebook Developer Toolkit 3.01. But I cannot find good documentation or sample code to get this working. Is this the only way to get Facebook.dll for .Net 2.0? If so where can I find a good documentation? Please guide me in the right direction.

Comment: we don't support .net 2.0 nor do we plan to support it as we use linq features in the fb c# sdk which you can easily convert it to for loop by downloading the source code. the fb developer toolkit and fb c# sdk are totally different projects.